# Brushless DC motor with built in controller and Teensy 4.1

Tags: arduino, brushless-dc-motor, teensy

I recently purchased a [brushless DC motor](https://www.robotshop.com/products/5840-3650-24v-27rpm-high-torque-worm-gear-motor). This motor is pretty much [this one](https://www.aslongdcmotor.com/sale-14421115-5840-3650-40rpm-bldc-brushless-dc-gear-motor-high-torque-silent-for-curtain-machine.html)

It has a built-in controller very similar to this post:

[Brushless DC motor with built in controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590373/brushless-dc-motor-with-built-in-controller)

There are five wires: power, ground, PWM, frequency generator, and direction. I'm trying to use a Teensy 4.1 while powering the motor externally with a 24 V power supply.

My code looks like this:

```
int led = 13;
const int pwmPin = 2;
const int dirPin = 3;
const int fgPin = 4;

void setup() {
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pwmPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);

  // analogWriteResolution(13);
  analogWriteFrequency(pwmPin, 20000);
  
  // Setup Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
}

void loop() {
  // turn motor off for two seconds
  analogWrite(pwmPin, 256);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  
  // Prompt user to enter key before starting
  Serial.println("Enter any letter key to start code");
  String entry = "";
  
  while (entry.length() < 2) {
    if (Serial.available()) {
      char inChar = Serial.read();
      entry += inChar;
      }
  }
  Serial.println("Running script now.");
  
  // turn motor on and spin 
  Serial.println("Turning");
  digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
  analogWrite(pwmPin, 128);
  delay(2000);           

  // turn motor on and spin in opposite direction
  Serial.println("Turning other direction");
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
  analogWrite(pwmPin, 128);
  delay(2000);
}
```

I upload the code, open the serial monitor, turn on my power supply, and the motor spins. However, it doesn't appear that my `analogWrite()` functions are changing the speed, regardless of what duty cycle I use. The wiring is very similar to [this brushless motor](https://cdn.robotshop.com/rbm/a00a7635-653b-4220-aac9-b0c23c5c5e2c/e/e9f91b3f-b88d-4a70-8636-cfd4de16cb9c/3f4002cb_36PG-3650BL-12V.pdf).

I noted that a high signal on the PWM wire causes the motor to stop, while a low signal causes it to move, so I've been setting the duty cycle in the first `analogWrite()` function in the loop to 256 see if I can get the motor to stop spinning when I supply power. I also tried setting the duty cycle to zero, but the motor still spins. No matter what duty cycle I try to write, the motor just spins at what I assume is 100% duty cycle.

Does anyone know why this might be the case? All of my wiring is correct, and it's a relatively simple program. I'm fairly new to coding all of this, so I'm hoping it's just a careless error on my part, and any help would be appreciated! Please let me know if you need any more information.

EDIT 1: Just as a side note, I know the controller isn't broken. I managed to control the speed just fine using a bunch of Tinkerforge bricks/bricklets (i.e. the servo brick and io4 bricklet). For my project, I need to use the Teensy, though.

EDIT 2: Added link to motor from actual supplier (Aslong)

Comment: Well the motor isn't brushless, but that may not effect anything since you're using a controller anyway.

Comment: Sending a 256 is asking for trouble. You should keep the input values in the range of 0-255. Your input of 256 is likely rolling back to 0, so on 100%.

Comment: Try setting the duty cycle to 250.

Comment: Tried duty cycle at 250, 255, and 1, but with no luck. Motor keeps spinning at the same speed. Thanks though!

Comment: _"I noted that a high signal on the PWM wire causes the motor to stop"_ - yes, that's what it says in your ('similar') datasheet. When you set the 'analog' output to 255, what voltage/waveform do you see on it? Is it different from when you send a 'high' signal?

Comment: I just used an oscilloscope to see what the waveforms looked like when I set the duty cycle to 255, and its essentially a constant 3.3V signal, which makes sense. I set the duty cycle to 128 just to make sure the Teensy pin wasn't busted, and the waveform looks as it should (i.e. 50% duty cycle). I then used digitalWrite() to set the pin to HIGH. Still no change in motor speed.

Comment: why do you call the motors brushless?

Comment: I call the motor brushless because this is the motor (sorry for not providing this earlier): https://www.aslongdcmotor.com/sale-14421115-5840-3650-40rpm-bldc-brushless-dc-gear-motor-high-torque-silent-for-curtain-machine.html

Comment: When you were using the "Tinkerforge bricks/bricklets", were you able to get an oscilloscope trace to see what the signal looks like? I see the product listing mentions 0-5 V for the PWM, so the controller might be malfunctioning with 3.3 V PWM

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing haha! I just used the scope to see the output PWM from the Tinkerforge servo brick and saw that it was outputting a 5V PWM when I commanded the motor to move. However, interesting enough, when the PWM output was 0V with Tinkerforge, the motor is completely stopped until I send it 5V PWM. This is unlike the Teensy, where the motor spins upon power-up even when the Teensy PWM output is 0V.

Answer (score 1):

Solution! I didn't connect the ground pin on the Teensy to the ground on the external power supply. I just had the Teensy plugged into the USB port. Now everything works fine.

For any others with the problem, I found that the motor doesn't spin when the PWM duty cycle is at 0%, unlike what the data sheets say.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: are you saying that you disconnected the ground and it started to work?

Comment: Sounds like he forgot to hook up the signal ground before.